# DataTables plugin: fnDraw doesn't work

Tags: datatables

I'm using dataTables plugin with the following configuration:

```js
$('#userList').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "sDom": 'frt',//no pagination
    "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
    "aoColumnDefs": [ 
        { "sClass": "center", "aTargets": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] },
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0, 2, 4, 5, 6] },
        { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [0, 6] },
        {
            "aTargets": [4],
            "mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
                if(data == 1)
                    return '<img src="../assets/img/icons/star.png" class="star-link" id="star-' + row[6] +'"/>';
                else
                    return '';
        },
        {
            "aTargets": [5],
            "mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return '<a href="#" class="action-link" id="action-' + row[6] +'">' + data + '</a>';
        }
    }
],
"sAjaxSource": url,
fnServerData: function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
    aoData.push( {'name':'channelName', 'value':channelName} );
    aoData.push( {'name':'ajax', 'value':true} );
    aoData.push( {'name':'action', 'value':'getUserList'} );
    $.ajax({
        "dataType": "json",
        "type": "POST",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": aoData,
        "success": fnCallback
    });
},
....
```

As you can see I'm using the `fnServerData` function to pass the data to the server with POST method. This code works well. But I need to refresh the table content on some events.
I have tried `fnReloadAjax()`, but it doesn't work with `bServerSide` set to true. Also, I have tried `fnDraw`, but it doesn't work: no data passed to the server.

Is there a solution, other than destroying and re-constructing the table?

Comment: Could you show the way you used fnDraw method?

Comment: `fnDraw` simply redraws the table. If you want to refresh the table, simply wrap the above code into a function and call that with option `bDestroy`.